# Calling flash file in iphone application

Tags: iphone, flash, xcode, titanium

Can anybody suggest me how to call flash file in iphone application.
Is it possible or not?
Is there any way to call flash file in iphone application?
Is it possible to call flash file in Titanium then we call titanium in iphone application.
Can any body suggest me in details?
waiting for your reply!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No it's not possible. Flash is not supported on iPhone

**Edit 1 (to OP's comment)**

---

No. The Flash player is not supported either in Safari on the iPhone or in iPhone apps.

As I understand Titanum (which I don't have much knowledge of) it is not a runtime but a compiler that compiles "web-languages" into specific files for each target platform, so there is no way to read the swf via Titanuim. In fact, I don’t think this would not be allowed on the iPhone anyway because (I think) the iPhone's sandbox doesn't allow any kind of external code to be read or JIT-compiled by an app.

Lack of Flash support is such a big deal, politically and economically, that if there was a way of reading Flash files on the iPhone you would have heard about it.

Comment: Is there any way to call flash file in iphone application? Is it possible to call flash file in Titanium then we call titanium in iphone application. Can any body suggest me in details? waiting for your reply!

Comment: hello,I have read a article in which i read that we can call flash file in titanium pls follow this link and suggest me.  http://www.smokycogs.com/blog/titanium-tutorials-embedding-flash-objects-in-a-titanium-window/

Comment: This may apply when you compile for different desktop environments, andriod and other platforms that support Flash. The fact remains, I'm sad to say, Flash is not supported on the iPhone